# Ubuntu 20.04. laptop closed lid issue

Tags: networking, laptop, connection, lid, systemd-logind

I am solving a minor issue with my Ubuntu 20.04. Focal fossa.
This might be relevant for all users using a laptop closed aside with an external display.
Whenever I shutdown or reboot the computer (laptop) **with a closed lid,** the computer after new start (or reboot) does not connect to the network (no wifi found) and when I want to restart, reboot, or shut down from the interface menu, it does not react at all.
Command-line „reboot“ returns this.

`~$ reboot`

`Failed to reboot system via logind: There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress`

I must close the lid after loading the Ubuntu interface to avoid any problems.

If I do not close the lid at all, everything is working fine.
My **logind.conf** looks like:

````
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=ignore
#HandleHibernateKey=ignore
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
Laptop:
Ubuntu 20.04.LTS Focal fossa
system         Aspire V7-582PG
bus              Dazzle_HW
memory         128KiB BIOS
processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 
memory         32KiB L1 cache
memory         256KiB L2 cache
memory         3MiB L3 cache
memory         32KiB L1 cache
memory         6GiB System Memory
memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600
memory         2GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600```

Please, does anyone have suggestions on how to remove this issue?
Thank you in advance!
Petr
````

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I turn off the laptop with a closed lid, the network is also not working after the next start.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.  Specifically the lines:

```
#HandleSuspendKey=ignore
#HandleHibernateKey=ignore
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

which were originally:

```
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
```

Lines beginning with `#` show the default settings.  When you change a setting you also need to uncomment the line (delete the `#`) for it to take effect.

Except for that, I think you had the right idea attempting to change `HandleLidSwitch` and `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower` to `ignore`, so uncomment those two.

I would restore everything else back to the defaults.